# AndroidViewClient: unable to dump correctly the view

Tags: android, androidviewclient

I'm trying to use CulebraTester2 to dump the Window hierarchy. I'm testing an app where the text of some TextView changes: the first time I call `dumpWindowHierarchy` the obtained JSON content corresponds to the text shown, when the text changes and I try to call again `dumpWindowHierarchy`, the text of the TextView remains unaltered in the JSON even if it actually has changed in the app. I've noticed instead that the bounds change.
I need to get the actual text shown by the app, is there a way?
Thanks.

UPDATE

I've tried using the mrin9 provided api and also using python `vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_device.dump_window_hierarchy()` and the result is the same: the text is not updated.

A snippet of the JSON:

```
{
    "id": 38,
    "parent": 36,
    "text": "Si pensa che porti fortuna mangiare:",
    "package": "com.mypackage",
    "checkable": false,
    "clickable": false,
    "index": 2,
    "content_description": "",
    "focusable": false,
    "resource_id": "questionDataQuestionText",
    "enabled": true,
    "password": false,
    "long_clickable": false,
    "long_text": "android.view.View_questionDataQuestionText id=38 parent=36",
    "clazz": "android.view.View",
    "scrollable": false,
    "selected": false,
    "checked": false,
    "focused": false,
    "bounds": [
        150,
        648,
        930,
        1010
    ],
    "children": []
}
```

Comment: can you provide details on how you are calling `dumpWindowHierarchy` ? Are you using a CulebraTester2 client? python or any other language?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/dump-window-hierarchy and if possible provide a snippet of the json

Comment: I've tried with python and with the provided mrin9 api and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I added the clock widget to the home screen as it has a changing text that we can use as an example (otherwise we both should install the same app which might not be possible).

[image: clock widget]

Then, using this script I could verify the text changes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import time

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

def search(resource_id, children):
    if not children:
        return
    for child in children:
        if child.resource_id == resource_id:
            print(child.text)
            return
        search(resource_id, child.children)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
    vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, useuiautomatorhelper=True)

    while True:
        h = vc.uiAutomatorHelper.ui_device.dump_window_hierarchy()
        search('com.google.android.deskclock:id/clock', h.children)
        time.sleep(10)
```

and produces this output when run

```
⚠️ CulebraTester2 server should have been started and port redirected.
6:04
6:04
6:04
6:04
6:04
6:05
6:05
6:05
6:05
6:05
6:05
6:06
6:06
6:06
```

You can probably adapt the script and test your app.

Comment: I adapt the script and test my app but the problem of the text that is not updated remains. I found that if I tap the text before dump the window hierarchy then the text read from the script is correct: probably is a problem related to the app. Thank you for the help!